# Using Reg Query from CMD prompt, how can I return the Reg Key from searching for a specific value?

Tags: search, registry

Looking for a way to return the actual reg key when searching for a value.

For example, when I search for a value...

`For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Reg Query "HKCR" /S^|FindStr /I "searchstring" 2^>Nul') Do @Echo %%A`

I get the actual value as it should be returned using Reg Query...

> 1     REG_EXPAND_SZ     a_long_expanded_string_containing_the_searchstring

However, I'd like to have the actual reg key, containing the value, returned instead...

> HKCR\Installer\Products\1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF

Hope that makes sense.